# Kivy app using Pandas crashing on Android packaged using Buildozer

Tags: python, android, pandas, kivy, buildozer

I have a Python kivy based simple app which is referencing Pandas and very simple use of dataframes. As soon as Pandas is referenced mobile app crashes with the following error:

> ImportError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZNSt12length_errorD1Ev" referenced by "/data/data/org.test.notes/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/pandas/_libs/window/aggregations.so"...

Full stack trace:

```
2020-04-28 21:11:09.858 6678-6709/org.test.notes I/python:   File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/Notes/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 32, in <module>
2020-04-28 21:11:09.859 6678-6709/org.test.notes I/python:   File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/Notes/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/notes/pandas/__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
2020-04-28 21:11:09.860 6678-6709/org.test.notes I/python:   File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/Notes/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/notes/pandas/core/api.py", line 29, in <module>
2020-04-28 21:11:09.862 6678-6709/org.test.notes I/python:   File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/Notes/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/notes/pandas/core/groupby/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
2020-04-28 21:11:09.863 6678-6709/org.test.notes I/python:   File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/Notes/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/notes/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 60, in <module>
2020-04-28 21:11:09.863 6678-6709/org.test.notes I/python:   File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/Notes/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/notes/pandas/core/frame.py", line 124, in <module>
2020-04-28 21:11:09.864 6678-6709/org.test.notes I/python:   File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/Notes/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/notes/pandas/core/series.py", line 4572, in <module>
2020-04-28 21:11:09.864 6678-6709/org.test.notes I/python:   File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/Notes/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/notes/pandas/core/generic.py", line 10349, in _add_series_or_dataframe_operations
2020-04-28 21:11:09.865 6678-6709/org.test.notes I/python:   File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/Notes/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/notes/pandas/core/window/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
2020-04-28 21:11:09.865 6678-6709/org.test.notes I/python:   File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/Notes/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/notes/pandas/core/window/ewm.py", line 5, in <module>
2020-04-28 21:11:09.866 6678-6709/org.test.notes I/python: ImportError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZNSt12length_errorD1Ev" referenced by "/data/data/org.test.notes/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/pandas/_libs/window/aggregations.so"...
2020-04-28 21:11:09.866 6678-6709/org.test.notes I/python: Python for android ended.
```

If I remove Pandas the app works fine.

How to address this, should I go for package creation using android-for-python and include recipes as Pandas recipe is available? Right now I am using Buildozer.

Comment: Not sure what library is expected to provide this, but it's probably a p4a bug of some kind. Could you open an issue on the python-for-android github about it?

Comment: can I get the link for this topic, please?